# how to use user boolean from sqlite3 in flask

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, user-data

I encounter some issues when implementing extra rights for some users in my flask site. Using sqlite3 as user database, I fetch all user data upon logon in

```py
class MyView(ModelView):
    def is_accessible(self):
        return current_user.is_authenticated
    def inaccessible_callback(self, name, **kwargs):
        return redirect(url_for('login'))

@login_manager.user_loader
class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(15), unique=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(50), unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(80))
    admin = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False)


@application.route('/login', methods= ['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    form = LoginForm()
    global user
    if form.validate_on_submit():
           user = User.query.filter_by(username=form.username.data).first()
           if user:
               if check_password_hash(user.password, form.password.data):
                   login_user(user, remember=form.remember.data)
                   return redirect(url_for('dashboard'))
           return '<h1>Invalid username or password</h1>'
    return render_template('login.html', form = form)
```

User database looks like this:

```
id|username|email|password|admin
1|demo1|demo1@test.demo|sha256$encryptedpwd|1
2|demo2|demo2@test.demo|sha256$encryptedpwd|0
```

Now, users with `admin="0"` do not encounter issues. Users with `admin="1"` get sometimes the message:

```
Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.
```

The way I try to differentiate is:

```py
@application.route('/dashboard_changed', methods=['GET','POST'])
@login_required
def dashboard_changed():
    if current_user.admin:
        return render_template('dashboard_changed.html', name = current_user.username)
    else: 
        return render_template("nok.html")
```

Is the approach correct and should I look elsewhere to resolve the issues, or is there anything faulty with this approach?

UPDATE:
Accesslogs I found (last x-lines):

```
10.233.34.77   [19/Apr/2021:14:38:26 +0200] "GET /%7B%7Burl_for('.static',%20filename='startertemplate.css')%7D%7D HTTP/1.1" 404 362 "http://10.233.11.249/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/7$
10.233.34.77   [19/Apr/2021:14:38:26 +0200] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 680 "" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0" ""
10.233.34.77   [19/Apr/2021:14:38:28 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 1646 "" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0" ""
10.233.34.77   [19/Apr/2021:14:38:28 +0200] "GET /static/startertemplate.css HTTP/1.1" 404 232 "https://kiwidata.demo.be/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0" ""
10.233.34.77   [19/Apr/2021:14:38:29 +0200] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 232 "" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0" ""
10.233.34.77   [19/Apr/2021:14:38:31 +0200] "GET /login HTTP/1.1" 200 1676 "https://kiwidata.demo.be/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0" ""
10.233.34.77   [19/Apr/2021:14:38:32 +0200] "GET /static/signin.css HTTP/1.1" 404 232 "https://kiwidata.demo.be/login" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0" ""
10.233.34.77   [19/Apr/2021:14:38:34 +0200] "POST /login HTTP/1.1" 302 227 "https://kiwidata.demo.be/login" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0" ""
10.233.34.77   [19/Apr/2021:14:38:34 +0200] "GET /dashboard HTTP/1.1" 200 8075 "https://kiwidata.demo.be/login" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0" ""
10.233.34.77   [19/Apr/2021:14:38:34 +0200] "GET /static/dashboard.css HTTP/1.1" 200 2059 "https://kiwidata.demo.be/dashboard" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0" ""
10.233.34.77   [19/Apr/2021:14:38:35 +0200] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 232 "https://kiwidata.demo.be/dashboard" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0" ""
10.233.34.77   [19/Apr/2021:14:38:37 +0200] "GET /dashboard_changed HTTP/1.1" 200 8429 "https://kiwidata.demo.be/dashboard" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0" ""
10.233.34.77   [19/Apr/2021:14:38:38 +0200] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 232 "https://kiwidata.demo.be/dashboard_changed" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0" ""
10.233.34.77   [19/Apr/2021:14:38:39 +0200] "GET /dashboardasp HTTP/1.1" 200 3344 "https://kiwidata.demo.be/dashboard_changed" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0" ""
10.233.34.77   [19/Apr/2021:14:38:40 +0200] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 232 "https://kiwidata.demo.be/dashboardasp" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0" ""
10.233.34.77   [19/Apr/2021:14:38:42 +0200] "GET /switchselectasp/DCA HTTP/1.1" 200 4848 "https://kiwidata.demo.be/dashboardasp" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0" ""
10.233.34.77   [19/Apr/2021:14:38:43 +0200] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 232 "https://kiwidata.demo.be/switchselectasp/DCA" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0" ""
10.233.34.77   [19/Apr/2021:14:38:45 +0200] "GET /switchselectasp/DCU HTTP/1.1" 200 3776 "https://kiwidata.demo.be/switchselectasp/DCA" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0" ""
10.233.34.77   [19/Apr/2021:14:38:45 +0200] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 232 "https://kiwidata.demo.be/switchselectasp/DCU" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0" ""
10.233.34.77   [19/Apr/2021:14:38:48 +0200] "GET /switchselectasp/M HTTP/1.1" 200 3741 "https://kiwidata.demo.be/switchselectasp/DCU" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0" ""
10.233.34.77   [19/Apr/2021:14:38:48 +0200] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 232 "https://kiwidata.demo.be/switchselectasp/M" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0" ""
10.233.34.77   [19/Apr/2021:14:38:50 +0200] "GET /switchselectasp/GS HTTP/1.1" 500 290 "https://kiwidata.demo.be/switchselectasp/M" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0" ""
10.233.34.77   [19/Apr/2021:14:38:51 +0200] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 232 "https://kiwidata.demo.be/switchselectasp/GS" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0" ""
10.233.34.77   [19/Apr/2021:14:38:53 +0200] "GET /switchselectasp/GS HTTP/1.1" 200 5019 "https://kiwidata.demo.be/switchselectasp/M" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0" ""
10.233.34.77   [19/Apr/2021:14:38:53 +0200] "GET /static/dashboard.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "https://kiwidata.demo.be/switchselectasp/GS" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0" ""
10.233.34.77   [19/Apr/2021:14:38:53 +0200] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 232 "https://kiwidata.demo.be/switchselectasp/GS" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0" ""
10.233.34.77   [19/Apr/2021:14:39:02 +0200] "GET /switchselectasp/HE HTTP/1.1" 500 290 "https://kiwidata.demo.be/switchselectasp/GS" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0" ""
10.233.34.77   [19/Apr/2021:14:39:03 +0200] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 232 "https://kiwidata.demo.be/switchselectasp/HE" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0" ""
10.233.34.77   [19/Apr/2021:14:39:04 +0200] "GET /switchselectasp/HE HTTP/1.1" 500 290 "https://kiwidata.demo.be/switchselectasp/GS" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0" ""
10.233.34.77   [19/Apr/2021:14:39:05 +0200] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 232 "https://kiwidata.demo.be/switchselectasp/HE" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0" ""
10.233.34.77   [19/Apr/2021:14:39:05 +0200] "GET /switchselectasp/HE HTTP/1.1" 500 290 "https://kiwidata.demo.be/switchselectasp/GS" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0" ""
10.233.34.77   [19/Apr/2021:14:39:05 +0200] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 232 "https://kiwidata.demo.be/switchselectasp/HE" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0" ""
10.233.34.77   [19/Apr/2021:14:39:05 +0200] "GET /switchselectasp/HE HTTP/1.1" 500 290 "https://kiwidata.demo.be/switchselectasp/GS" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0" ""
10.233.34.77   [19/Apr/2021:14:39:06 +0200] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 232 "https://kiwidata.demo.be/switchselectasp/HE" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0" ""
10.233.34.77   [19/Apr/2021:14:39:06 +0200] "GET /switchselectasp/HE HTTP/1.1" 200 5349 "https://kiwidata.demo.be/switchselectasp/GS" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0" ""
10.233.34.77   [19/Apr/2021:14:39:06 +0200] "GET /static/dashboard.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "https://kiwidata.demo.be/switchselectasp/HE" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0" ""
10.233.34.77   [19/Apr/2021:14:39:06 +0200] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 232 "https://kiwidata.demo.be/switchselectasp/HE" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0" ""
```

Error logs:

```
2021/04/19 08:45:27 [error] 1442#0: *661 open() "/kiwi_app/templates/{{url_for('.static', filename='starter-template.css')}}" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 10.233.34.77, server: _, request: "GET /%7B%7Burl_for('.static'$
2021/04/19 08:45:27 [error] 1442#0: *661 open() "/kiwi_app/templates/404.html" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 10.233.34.77, server: _, request: "GET /%7B%7Burl_for('.static',%20filename='starter-template.css')%7D%7D HTTP$
2021/04/19 08:45:27 [error] 1442#0: *661 open() "/kiwi_app/templates/favicon.ico" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 10.233.34.77, server: _, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", host: "10.233.11.249"
2021/04/19 08:45:27 [error] 1442#0: *661 open() "/kiwi_app/templates/404.html" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 10.233.34.77, server: _, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", host: "10.233.11.249"
2021/04/19 14:38:26 [error] 25725#0: *1 open() "/kiwi_app/templates/{{url_for('.static', filename='starter-template.css')}}" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 10.233.34.77, server: _, request: "GET /%7B%7Burl_for('.static',$
```

Comment: Changed the example, it was already in place...
Anyhow, the error would only appear if the user is not an admin, right? And it's only the admins that encounter issues

Comment: ok, thanks for mentioning that, was not aware of it. changed it! 
Where can I find those error tracebacks?

Comment: Put the error logs in the question

Answer (score 0):

I've found the issue, just to be complete...
The example above provided (off course not the complete code) was correct.
I differentiate between admins and not admin by if `current_user.admin:`

```
@application.route('/dashboard_changed', methods=['GET','POST'])
@login_required
def dashboard_changed():
    if current_user.admin:
        return render_template('dashboard_changed.html', name = current_user.username)
    else: 
        return render_template("nok.html")
```

In an other route used often I used `if user.is_admin:` which, despite the fact is mentioned in a lot off tutorials and fora, didn't work out in my environment...